# Form will not send on some devices... usually Android

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, forms

I used a form template that I found online... It usually works on iOS and desktop but I never receive the email when someone submits from an Android device. I'm not sure if the issue is with the javascript or the PHP.

I'm a pretty novice programmer... at best. I also know that something screwy is up with my jQuery scripts because I'm getting about 6 error messages when I inspect in Chrome.

Looking to humbly listen and learn from whoever has the time/answers.

page containing form:

```
     <html>
     <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"       
    />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
    scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" 
    rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
        scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/demo.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/form-mini.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
  family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href='assets/custom.css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" 
rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bd7093c7c8.js" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script 
src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    </head>
    <body>

    <form method="post" id="regForm" action="submit.php" role="form">
      <h1>Register:</h1>
      <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
      <div class="tab">First Name:
        <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className     
    = ''" name="sender"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">Contact Info:
        <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = 
   ''" name="senderEmail" type="email"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''" 
    name="phone" type="tel"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">Your first 5 questions:
        <p><input placeholder="1..." oninput="this.className = ''" 
    name="question1"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="2..." oninput="this.className = ''" 
    name="question2"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="3..." oninput="this.className = ''" 
    name="question3"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="4..." oninput="this.className = ''" 
    name="question4"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="5..." oninput="this.className = ''" 
    name="question5"></p>
      </div>
      <div style="overflow:auto;">
        <div style="float:right;">
          <button type="button" id="prevBtn" 
     onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
          <button type="button" id="nextBtn" 
     onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
      <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
        <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
      </div>
     </form>

     <script>
  var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
 showTab(currentTab); // Display the crurrent tab

 function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step 
indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById('regForm').submit();
    event.preventDefault(); 
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
 }

 function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " 
 finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>


Code that sends:

<?php

if(count($_POST) > 1) {
    $recipient="mackaroto@gmail.com";
    $subject="New Registration";
    $sender=$_POST["sender"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
    $phone=$_POST["phone"];
    $question1=$_POST["question1"];
    $question2=$_POST["question2"];
    $question3=$_POST["question3"];
    $question4=$_POST["question4"];
    $question5=$_POST["question5"];
    $mailBody="Name: $sender\n\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\nPhone: 
    $phone\n\n1. $question1\n\n2. $question2\n\n3.$question3\n\n4. 
    $question4\n\n5. $question5";

        var_dump(mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender         
     <$senderEmail>"));


  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Please halp... someone? Anyone?